# In a 100-grid why isn't the total sum of 16 squares (in an irregular shape) divisible by 16?

Tags: recreational-mathematics, problem-solving, education

It should be noted:
* by value I'm referring to the total sum of the numbers in the 'chunk'
* each square is a number from 1 - 100 in order
* no chunks can be adjoined by corners or have gaps in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I understand correctly but why should it be?
if you pick a number, x going right/left on the grid will add x+1/x-1 going down/up will add x+10/x-10.
by adding 16 numbers that way you get 16x+Y, Y doesn't have to be divisible by 16.